# Showing an HTML element while in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show an HTML element while a loop is running, unfortunately, my approach doesn't seem to work:

```js
function mainFunction() {
    $( '#myElement').removeClass( 'hidden');    
    $( 'div.otherElements').each( function() {
        doSomething();
    });
    $( '#myElement').addClass( 'hidden');
}
```

The `removeClass()` and `addClass()` calls work fine on their own, so does the loop. My suspicion is, that the loop starts before the `.removeClass()` call has finished and the call waits until the end of the loop, so it never really shows on screen, since `.removeclass()` and `.addClass()` happen nearly at the same time. If I use `console.log()` instead of the jquery calls, it shows the same behaviour. When I call `mainFunction()` the first `.console.log()` does not show up before the loop has finished.

I already tried to put the loop in another function, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: What if you invoked your loop using `setTimer` instead of calling it directly?

Comment: Javascript runs *very* fast.  The javascript will not wait for the browser to have a chance to redraw before proceeding with it's logic.  It is highly likely that your logic is finishing before the browser is being given a chance to perform a redraw/reflow so you are not seeing the effect.

Comment: As @Taplar said, have you verified that the `doSomething()` is taking long enough that `#myElement` would be visible long enough to notice? You can see if it is working if you were to put an alert in your loop, forcing the js to stop until you hit ok each time. If you can see your element while the alert it up, then the js is most likely just running to fast.

Comment: No it's not too fast, the loop takes a while (about 3-5 seconds), that's why I want the element to show an animation, so the user knows it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change to the class list won't be effectuated until the callstack is empty. You can force this with a timeout of 0. This example is very clunky but will get the job done.

```js
   function pause(milliseconds) {
      var dt = new Date();
      while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
   }

    function doSomething() {
      pause(500); 
    }
    
    function mainFunction() {
        $( '#myElement').removeClass( 'hidden');    
        setTimeout(() => {
            $( 'div.otherElements').each( function() {
                doSomething();
            });
            $( '#myElement').addClass( 'hidden');
        }, 0);
    }
    
    mainFunction();
```

```css
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="otherElements"></div>
<div class="otherElements"></div>
<div class="otherElements"></div>
<div class="otherElements"></div>
<div class="otherElements"></div>
<div class="otherElements"></div>

<div id="myElement" class="hidden">Doing important work</div>
```

Comment: Wish I'd thought of that, although why do you use `setTimeout` to hide the element at the end?

Comment: @ScottHunter It seemed like a good idea at the time, but you're right, it is probably not needed.

Comment: Updated the answer with a working example. And @ScottHunter, you were right. The timeout for hiding element is not needed.

Comment: @korguell If the answer is to your liking, would you please mark it as the accepted answer?